# Captcha not working on adding session_regenerate_id(true);

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, captcha

I want to add session_regenerate_id(true); in my PHP website, as i want to generate different session id before and after successful authentication. But after adding this code, my captcha is not working and giving error of invalid captcha.

How can i manage both things. I don not want to add Math captcha or without session captcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to regenerate a CAPTCHA image after regenerating the session ID:

```
    session_start(); // start or resume a session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerate the session ID
    
    // regenerate the CAPTCHA image
    $captcha_image = generate_captcha_image(); // your CAPTCHA image generation function
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha_image; // store the CAPTCHA image in the session
```

Comment: After using the above code. The captcha start working. Somehow few pages in the website is getting logout when i am trying to perform some action. Only few pages have this problem, rest is working fine. Can you please help in this? What can be the issue?